# UITableView within Subclassed UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a UIView that I subclassed to use as a slideout menu. Prior to trying to implement a tableview, I had programmatically added buttons with images and titles. It worked fine.

Currently I'm working with a subclassed UIView with a UITableView on top. I have a subclassed UITableViewCell and both subclasses have xibs.

The problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to have the tableview show up. I have the delegate methods in place as well as setting the tableviewcell as the dequeued cell.

The question I would like to figure out is how to get the tableview to show up. The background of the menu shows up but no tableview on top. Thanks for the help.

Comment: i suggest you to follow this tutorial -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tJJMyzdB9uI

Comment: Where is this `UIView` added as a subview to the view heirarchy? Where is the `UITableView` added as a subview to the `UIView`? Can you share some code?

Comment: The UIView was a programmatically added to the View Controller when it loaded. Then when the button is pressed, it would animate to another position (slide out) so the user could see it. Due to time constraints, the tableview on the view has been pushed aside and the original state mentioned in the post will be used. I would however like to see what comes of this in hopes of using it later and helping others.